# Theorem regarding continuously differentiable functions

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand the proof of a theorem in Flanigan's *Complex Variables*:

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a domain and let $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Let $u \in \mathcal{C}^{1}(\Omega)$ (set of continuously differentiable functions on $\Omega$) with $z_0=(x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$. For each point $z=(x,y) \in \Omega$, we may write $$u(z)=u(z_0)+u_x(z_0) \cdot (x-x_0)+u_y(z_0) \cdot (y-y_0)+\varepsilon_1 \cdot (x-x_0)+ \varepsilon_2 \cdot (y-y_0),$$
where $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ approach $0$ as $z$ approaches $z_0$ in $\Omega$.

proof. Observe that $(u(x,y)-u(x_0,y_0)=\{u(x,y)-u(x_0,y)\}+\{u(x_0,y)-u(x_0,y_0)\}$. The mean value theorem may be applied to the $x$-variable in the first bracket and $y$-variable in the second. This yields the equality with the right hand side of the last equation with $$(\star) \hspace{1mm} u_x(x_1,y) \cdot (x-x_0)+u_y(x_0,y_1) \cdot (y-y_0)$$

for $x_1$ between $x_0$ and $x$ and $y_1$ between $y_0$ and $y$.

**First question**: How exactly do we apply the mean value theorem to get the expression $(\star)$? I'm confused what steps are done to arrive at this expression and what the $x_1$ and $y_1$ are.

continuing the proof: $(\ast)$ The continuity of partial derivatives allow us to conclude that $u_x(x_1,y)$, $u_y(x_0,y_1)$ approach $u_x(x_0,y_0)$, $u_y(x_0,y_0)$, respectively, as $(x,y)$ approaches $(x_0,y_0)$. $(\ast)$ Hence we may write $$\begin{align} u_x(x_1,y)&=u_x(x_0,y_0)+ \varepsilon_1  \\ u_y(x_0,y_1)&=u_y(x_0,y_0)+ \varepsilon_2 \end{align}$$
where $\varepsilon_i \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)$

For the part between $(\ast)$, could someone elaborate why this is the case?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value theorem states that
$$ u(x,y) - u(x_0,y) = (x-x_0) \left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right|_{x_1,y}
$$
for some $x_1 \in [x,x_0]$. Substituting the above equation for $u(x,y) - u(x_0,y)$ leads to the next step.

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then
$$ \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)
$$
Since $u_x$ is continuous, 
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)} u_x(x_1,y) = u_x(x,y)
$$
and similarly for $u_y$.